# Robot class not working in a for loop in selenium webdriver for a code to upload files one after another

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to upload files one after another using for loop. I am using the Robot class for **Ctrl+ V** operation as I am having a windows browse windows which cannot be located using `findelement` and `sendkeys`.
The file upload works perfectly fine once but does not work subsequently for for loop iterations. The **Ctrl+V** operation is not performed in the Robot class.

I have tried giving `robot1.delay(10000);` before Enter but it did not work. Also `driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());` did not work.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-item col-xs-12']/input[@id='upload']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"upload-form\"]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/span"));
            fileInput.click();



    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(BusinessUtils.path);

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
//Ctrl+v


            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Robot robot1 = new Robot();
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot1.delay(10000);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("comment")).sendKeys("GGAT Test");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Upload Started");

}
```

The **Ctrl+V** is not working and more than one file is not getting uploaded.

Comment: probably not the issue, but you should probably just create one robot outside of the loop instead of creating a new one each time... should probably do that for the clipboard, too.  Seems like that's always the same?  Why not set the clipboard before the loop?

Comment: I tried setting the loop before the robot, but it did not make any difference. The clipboard I am going to change, so may well be inside the loop.